# latex - includegraphic with variables in the name

Tags: r, includegraphics, sweave

I'm no pro when it comes to latex and I'm working on something that's already been a bit established. I have a batch that produces multiple pdfs with a latex/sweave template. I'm attempted to insert a graphic that has a variable in the name but I'm striking out bad. I'm hoping I can get some help cleaning it up.

The code I'm trying...

```
\newpage
\subsec{graphic page}
\rptpage{ \showtitle{} }
graphicsrc <- sprintf('name\_with\_underscores\_%02d.pdf', objectnum)

\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{graphicsrc}
@
```

objectnum is a passed variable.

Everything works fine if I run the script with everything hard coded as such:

```
\newpage
\subsec{graphic page}
\rptpage{ \showtitle{} }
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{name_with_underscores_01.pdf}
@
```

The problem is, I can't hard code these to run them individually. I'm really hoping someone can help me debug the syntax issues I'm hitting!!

Comment: its more of an R question than a latex one so I can't help really,  and it's unrelated to includegraphics, if the R graphicsrc  has the string `name_with_underscore`  (you shouldn't need `\_` I think) then it's just a general question of how you put that R value into the generated latex (the fact that it is the argument of `\includegraphics` shoudln't matter I think, you are just generating the latex code as a string.

Comment: unrelated but `width=\paperwidth` looks suspicious, normally `\paperwidth` is wider than `\textwidth` so this will not fit in the allotted space.

Answer (score 1):

This has the `sweave` tag,  but what you show is not a complete LaTeX document with well delimited R code, but a chunk of  hodgepodge of LaTeX plus R commands, including (maybe) the end of R code (`@` line) but without any start of a R code chunk (`<>>>=` line), so it is difficult guess what are you doing really, but it seems unnecessarily complicated:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

<<objectnum,echo=F>>=
# Advanced method to set the variable:
graphicsrc <- 'example-image'
@

% Advanced method to use the variable as   filename of an image
<<echo=F,out.width="2cm",fig.cap="Example figure taking the variable name in R",fig.align='center'>>=
include_graphics(graphicsrc)
@

% Less advanced method 
\begin{figure}[h]\centering
\includegraphics[width=2cm]{\Sexpr{graphicsrc}}
\caption{The same variable used in \LaTeX\ code}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

BTW, as you can see in the example, you do not need to declare the extension of the image, except for disambiguation purposes (e.g., when you have `foo.png` and `foo.pdf`  but  you must use  "foo.pdf" and not "foo.png").

On the other hand, do not see the use of `[h]` as a good practice. It was convenient only for this example.